# ExtJS trigger "change" event on setValue for selectfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm setting the value to a select field, using the `setValue` method, and on the `change` listener i do some work. 
The problem is that the setValue method does not trigger the change event.
Any idea how can i do this?

**Update:**

this is my select:

```
  xtype: 'selectfield',
  id: 'category_id',
  name: 'category_select',
  label: 'Categoria',
  options: [],
  listener : { //my logic goes here }
```

somewhere in my code (the change listener of anoher select) i load the items like this :

```
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.categories.length; i++) {
        Ext.getCmp('category_id').setOptions([{ text: jsonData.categories[i].category_name, value: jsonData.categories[i].category_id}], true);
  }
```

and then I set the value :

```
  if (jsonData.categories.length > 0) {
        Ext.getCmp('category_id').setValue(jsonData.categories[0].category_id);
  } else {
        Ext.getCmp('category_id').setValue("");
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Shekhar! I've added some code

Comment: setValue() fires the change event for me. I'm not positive but whatever you set the value to needs to be a value that already exists in the selectfield.